# Dropdown menu fed from auth_user

Tags: python, html, django

So I got to the end of my tether. I need to create a database that allows me to choose user names stored in auth_user table in the 'username' column. The model.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class basehw(models.Model):

    name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    dept = models.CharField(verbose_name='dept', max_length=50, null=False)
    location = models.CharField(verbose_name='location', max_length=50, null=False)
```

form:

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
from baza.models import basehw


    class baseForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            def __init__(self):
                pass

            model = basehw
```

add.html template(for now, it's a text field):

```
    {% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="{% static 'base/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js' %}"></script> </head>
    <body>

<form action="{% url 'baza.views.add' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="name">name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name" name="name">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="site">site:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="site" name="site">
            <option value="W16">W16</option>
            <option value="W1602">W1602</option>
        </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="hostname">hostname:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hostname" name="hostname" placeholder="hostname">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="SN">serial number:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SN" name="SN" placeholder="serial number">
</div>

    </div>

    <br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="save"/>
    <a href="{% url 'baza.views.Table' %}" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" >cancel</a>
    <br /><br />


</form>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def Table(request):
    table = basehw.objects.all
    return render_to_response('../templates/baza/baza.html',
        {'table': table},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = baseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baza/')
    else:
        form = baseForm()

    return render(request, 'baza/add.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Using the following model, I am able to populate the 'name' field only by using the id of the whole record. Namely, when I enter '1', I get the user name that was saved as first in the auth_user table, when '2', the second one... Moreover, such model allows me to update the 'name' field only – no other field are possible to alter. The application uses an HTML template, and I'd like to turn the 'name' field to dropdown menu. So the problems are:

- How should I create the model in order to make all fields editable?
- What should I do to select a user's name instead of an ID from dropdown menu (dropdown menu fed from auth_user)? How should I describe  in HTML?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is impossible to answer as it is. Why can you only edit the name field? Are you using a form - if so what does it look like? What does the template look like?

Comment: I've pasted the from.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you write a template for a Django form. You need to use the form fields provided by the form object. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{ form.name.label_tag }}
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ form.name.errors }}
</div>
```